# Passing parameters to shell script from IDL script

Tags: shell, spawn, idl-programming-language

I'm trying to write IDL script called, for example, a.pro. In the end of this script I want to execute shell script b. I'm trying to do it using spawn command. But I also need to pass some parameters (variables values) to this shell script from IDL script. How can I do that?

Comment: You could use the `EXECUTE` function on a string and pass the variable in that way.

Comment: The [tag:idl] tag is for  Interface Description Language.

Answer (score 3):

The command you send to `SPAWN` is just a string; create the string any way you like. I prefer using C-style format codes:

```
filename = 'output.log'
n_lines = 50
cmd = string(n_lines, filename, format='(%"tail -%d %s")')
; cmd = 'tail -50 output.log'
spawn, cmd, output
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to call [`SPAWN`](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/SPAWN.html) to accomplish what you want:

---

Call the script, `b`, directly:

```
spawn, ['b', arg1, arg2], /noshell
```

Advantages:

- Faster, because it doesn't create a new instance of `bash`.
- Safer, because you don't have to escape or quote the arguments.

---

Format as a `bash` terminal string:

```
script_path = 'b'
cmd = strjoin([script_path, arg1, arg2], ' ')
spawn, cmd
```

Advantages:

- Sometimes easier, because you can just use the format you're used to seeing from `bash`.

---

In most instances, you should call scripts and other programs (besides IDL) directly with `spawn, /noshell`, because the speed gains are substantial, and the safety may be considerable.